# Setstate not updating the UI in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I am building the form based on the JSON data. I loop through the questions list and generate the Radio buttons. I am storing the values of radio button selection in `formDatas` list.

Radio button values are updated in `formDatas` but UI is not updating after the selection, I am not sure what am I missing

```
class Questionnaire extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QuestionnaireState createState() => _QuestionnaireState();
}

class _QuestionnaireState extends State<Questionnaire> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<Widget> fieldList = [];
  List<dynamic> questions = [
    {
      "minLabel": {"en": "default"},
      "maxValue": null,
      "type": "SWITCH",
      "weightLogics": [],
      "maxLabel": {"en": "default"},
      "enabled": false,
      "points": null,
      "minValue": null,
      "includeInScore": false,
      "intro": {"en": "default"},
      "name": "",
      "options": [
        {
          "id": "jhjhkjhk",
          "choiceFeedback": "true",
          "correct": false,
          "choiceText": {"en": "Yes"},
          "value": 0.0,
          "seq": 0.0
        },
        {
          "id": "sjgjsf",
          "choiceFeedback": "false",
          "correct": false,
          "choiceText": {"en": "No"},
          "value": 0.0,
          "seq": 1.0
        }
      ],
      "id": "0sdlfsdf",
      "text": {"en": "Are you new"}
    },
  ];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> formDatas = [];
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    questions.forEach((question) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = {'questionId': question["id"], 'value': ''};
      formDatas.add(data);
    });

    fieldList = createFields();
  }


  List<Widget> createFields() {
      questions.forEach((question) {
        if (question['type'] == 'SWITCH') {
          fieldList.add(createRadioFields(question));
        }
      });
    return fieldList;
  }

  Widget createRadioFields(question) {
    final index = formDatas.indexWhere((element) => element["questionId"] == question["id"]);
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1))
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(
            question["text"]["en"],
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
          ),
          Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: question['options']
                  .map<Widget>((option) => RadioListTile(
                      title: Text(option["choiceText"]["en"]),
                      value: option["choiceFeedback"],
                      groupValue: formDatas[index]["value"],
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          print(value);
                          formDatas[index]["value"] = value;
                          formDatas = formDatas;
                        });
                      }))
                  .toList())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget createForm() {
    return Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: fieldList),
        ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Questionnaire'),
        ),
        body: createForm());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `createFields()` only called in `initState()`, this will only ever run once, on first build.  After that, it will never be called again.  `setState()` will call the `build()` method again, but not `initState`.

So, move `createFields()` out of `initState` and into `build()`.

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    questions.forEach((question) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = {'questionId': question["id"], 'value': ''};
      formDatas.add(data);
    });

    //fieldList = createFields(); // move this into build ↓  ************
  }
```

The `build()` method of your StatefulWidget:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    fieldList = createFields(); // ← re/build fields ************

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Questionnaire'),
        ),
        body: createForm());
  }
```

Comment: I tried this, It results in appending radio buttons to existing fields. For Ex. As per the data App shows only one set of radio button in the beginning after the selection I see 2 sets of radio buttons in which one radio button is selected

Comment: I'm answering the question of "why UI is not updating after the selection", not solving the logic problems of how you've setup your page & altering the data.